I'm transforming.dita in .pdf using DITA-OT. I don't understand how to change the size of the headers?
Good afternoon! I am using Oxygen XML Author 26.1 to develop DITA document maps. Then I transform the file.dita to the file .pdf using DITA Open Toolkit 4.2.3 (preinstalled org.dita.pdf2 plugin). I was able to figure out how to change the size of the main font in the resulting pdf file. But I don't understand at all how I can change the size of the headers. I would be extremely grateful for your help. I'm not very good at XSLT.
I tried changing different values in the configuration files of the org.dita.pdf2 plugin, but I only managed to change the size of the main font.

In this XSLT stylesheet "DITA-OT/plugins/org.dita.pdf2/cfg/fo/attrs/topic-attr.xsl" you can find attribute sets like:
<xsl:attribute-set name="topic.title" 

or:
<xsl:attribute-set name="topic.topic.title"
which are applied and used depending on the level in the hierarhy.
In general one should avoid changing directly files in the PDF plugin folder according to the DITA OT docs: https://www.dita-ot.org/dev/topics/pdf-customization-approaches#ariaid-title1
There is also a book named "DITA For Print" by Leigh White which you may consider buying as it covers lots of customization capabilities.

Good afternoon! Thanks for the reply. I understood a lot. But I still don't understand how to make page breaks? So that each topic starts with a new page. I will definitely buy the book, thank you.
